# Field integrity exception updating with data loader

Tags: data-loader, exception

I'm facing an exception when updating 100 Products using Data Loader, it reads:

> field integrity exception: unknown (0068000000yNrDl|1|538115.4|540365.4|73|74,)"

Context:
The format of the error seems to be a reference to a record. The firs value is the Id of an Opportunity, other values are not related to the Opportunity in question since there are no fields with those values.
During the update process Products are updated, then PriceBookEntries with correct price, nothing to do with Opportunities so, I have no idea about the origin of the error and no clue about the meaning of the error message.

Has anyone seen an exception message like this one before? I would like some advice to help me understand what the error message means after all.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this link might help you, https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gov7AAA

Comment: Hi Santanu, thanks for your replay. I'm only editing the PriceBookEntry.UnitPrice based on the Product list price (a custom field that is been updated through Data Loader), that is accomplished on a method invoked from a trigger that detects when a Product price changed, then it goes to the PriceBookEntry and update the UnitPrice. That's why I said there is nothinig directly related to the Opp in this execution. Anyway, the error message is poor so I have no clue what it means or how to fix the error.

Comment: Better fix that and answer your own question, so others might get benefited

Comment: fix what? I have no answer to my question yet, my friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally can post **the answer for this issue**.

The original error message was indeed pointing to an Opportunity record with Id = "0068000000yNrDl". This Opportunity record was been updated by a trigger chained execution that started on the Product record and ended up on the Opp record.
The error cause is that the Opp record could not be edited because Stage="Order In" and there is a validation rule saying that Opps with that stage must have a Quote, and the Opp record did not have a Quote.
When I attempted to edit the Opp record directly from the layout, an internal SF error occurred and I couldn't do nothing but go back to the Opp record page.

Conclusion:
When attempting to update the Product, the Opp was updated internally as well, and an internal SF error occurred with no detailed message (as SF usually do) from data loader report.

Hope others to be able to find a solution here in the future for similar problems. Thanks to all that took interest in this question.
Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Add a column to your csv file with the header: "Use Standard Price" and set the value to FALSE for all rows.

[check the following link for detailed workaround](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000193277&type=1)

Comment: Hi oozkan, I've keep digging and it seems to be that some Opportunities are is a stage = "Order In" but have no Quote, so when attempting to edit those Opps (triggered in chain by a Product edition) an internal SF error happens and therefore, the Product is not properly edited.